# How to use variables from shell script in python script file?

Tags: python, bash

I have a shell script that has a command to run a python script. I want 4 variables (for eg: var1,var2,var3,var4) from the shell script to be used in the python script. Any suggestions how to do this?

For eg: I want to replace `"lastTest44"`, `firstTest44` and `A-S00000582` with variables from the shell script.

```
driver.find_element_by_id("findKey_input").clear() 
driver.find_element_by_id("findKey_input").send_keys("lastTest44") 
driver.find_element_by_id("ST_View_lastTest44, firstTest44").click() 
driver.find_element_by_link_text("A-S00000582").click()
```

Comment: for eg: I want to replace "lastTest44", firstTest44 and A-S00000582 with variables from shell script

driver.find_element_by_id("findKey_input").clear()       driver.find_element_by_id("findKey_input").send_keys("lastTest44")
driver.find_element_by_id("ST_View_lastTest44, firstTest44").click()
driver.find_element_by_link_text("A-S00000582").click()

Comment: You'll need to share what you've tried so far, or what the current code you have is. Try to keep it to the relevant portions, and not the entire script.

Comment: Pass the variables into python as command line arguments then use something like `getopt` to parse the command line arguments within your python script.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use command line arguments:

**Shell Script**

```
a=1
b=2
python test1.py "$a" "$b"
```

**Python Script**

```
import sys
var1 = sys.argv[1]
var2 = sys.argv[2]
print var1, var2
```

Comment: Thanks a ton ooga. 
Below are the commands I have in my python script (using webdriver for testing)
driver.find_element_by_id("findKey_input").clear() driver.find_element_by_id("findKey_input").send_keys("lastTest44") driver.find_element_by_id("ST_View_lastTest44, firstTest44").click() driver.find_element_by_link_text("A-S00000582").click()

1. How do I replace $a from shell script in place of "lastTest44" in the following command (driver.find_element_by_id("findKey_input").send_keys("lastTest44"))

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking to use are called command line arguments. These are parameters that are specified at the time of calling the particular piece of code you're looking to run.

In Python, these are accessible through the `sys` module under a variable called `argv`. This is an array of all the arguments passed in from the caller, where each value within the array is a string.

For example, say the code I'm writing takes in parameters to draw a square. This could require 4 parameters - An x coordinate, y coordinate, a width, and a height. The Python code for this might look like this:

```
import sys
x = sys.argv[1]
y = sys.argv[2]
width = sys.argv[3]
height = sys.argv[4]

# Some more code follows.
```

A few things to note:

1. Each argument is of type `string`. This means that in this case, I could not perform any sort of arithmetic until converting them into the correct types that I want.
2. The first argument in `sys.argv` is the name of the script being run. You'll want to make sure that you start reading from the second position in the array `sys.argv[1]` instead of the typical zero-th index like you normally would.

[There is some more detailed information here](http://www.faqs.org/docs/diveintopython/kgp_commandline.html), which could lead you to better ways of handling command line arguments. To get started though, this would work well enough.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you want:

```
2014-06-05 09:37:57 [tmp]$ export VAR1="a"
2014-06-05 09:38:01 [tmp]$ export VAR2="b"
2014-06-05 09:38:05 [tmp]$ export VAR3="c"
2014-06-05 09:38:08 [tmp]$ export VAR4="d"
2014-06-05 09:38:12 [tmp]$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Feb 27 2014, 19:58:35) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from os import environ
>>> environ['VAR1']
'a'
>>> environ['VAR2']
'b'
>>> environ['VAR3']
'c'
>>> environ['VAR4']
'd'
>>> environ['VAR5']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 23, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'VAR5'
```

Remember to catch KeyError and respond accordingly or use the get method (from the dict class) and specify a default to be used when the key is not present:

```
>>> environ.get('VAR5', 'not present')
'not present'
```

more:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html

Comment: In the interest sharing, you don't have to use a command line argument.  The OP didn't require a command line argument, but that doesn't preclude using environmental variables directly as well as command line arguments should you please.  Whoever did the -1, got a reason?  I'd be interested in knowing why you consider this a bad answer.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add for what worked for my case:

I have my variables in file which was being sourced in shell script.
Need to pass the variables to python from same file.
I have pandas and spark as well in my case
My expected result is to concatenate the path to pass in "tocsv" which is achieved

```
**Shell**:
. path/to/variable/source file # sourcing the variables
python path/to/file/extract.py "$OUTBOUND_PATH"


**Python**:
import sys
import pandas as pd
#If spark session is involved import the sparksession as well

outbound_path=sys.argv[1] #argument is collected from the file passed through shell
file_name="/report.csv"

geo.topandas().tocsv(outbound_path+file_name,mode="w+")
```